# Problem using TI CC2650

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments

I am asking this question directly on the TI forums as well, but decided to post here in case anyone has specific experience with this.

I am attempting to prototype with a CC2650 RGZ package 48 pin QFN processor from TI. I am trying to program it using the XDS100v3 debug probe on the SmartRF06 Evaluation board. The chip I am trying to program is a standalone, not the evaluation breakout board.

My only connections are a 3.3V power supply to VDDS, VDDS2, VDDS3, and the VDD_DCDC input. The DCDC output I have connected to the VDDR 1.8V inputs. My reset pin is tied through a pullup resistor to 3.3V. All pins listed above have capacitors to ground, as recommeded in the SmartRF documentation. When I tried just using that, I got 3.3V on the power rail and 5 mA being drawn from my power supply, as expected. So for that reason I believe my power connections are correct.

To program the board, I connected the cJTAG connections from the SmartRF06. This would be Pin 1 on the JTAG connector(VDD_Sense) to Power, Pin 4(Ground) to Ground, Pin 7(TMSC) to Pin 24 on the CC2650, and Pin 9(TCK) to Pin 25 on the CC2650. These follow chapter 7 recommendations from the programming guide. I ran CCS to program the board, and recieved the error "Power Failure on target CPU".

Following this, the CC2650 started drawing the current limit from my power supply at 30 mA. This persisted after I disconnected the JTAG pins. I think, therefore, that the chip was burnt somehow by the debugger. I do not, however, have any idea of why this happened.

On the SmartRF board, I disconnected the VDDtoEM jumper, but left the other default jumpers on. I also removed the evaluation breakout board. POWER switch was set to ON and BAT/USB was set to USB.

I have a couple days before my replacement chip comes in, but if anyone has experience with TI debuggers, specifically with designing boards using the CC2650, I would appreciate some advice on how I can program my chip.

For reference, here is the development kit I was using, which has the debugger onboard: http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2650dk

Thank you for any advice or help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got a full schematic to take a look at? I used the CC2650 Launchpad's debugger (XDS110) to program a custom board recently, and I removed all the headers however between the debugger and the EM. I would suggest doing the same on your debugger.